# Не работает привязка x:Name

Tags: xamarin

Вот простой XAML код

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="Label1"/>
    <Button Clicked="Button1_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Я хочу к примеру при нажатии на кнопку изменить текст Label1 на Hello World

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Hello World!";
}
```

Но когда я обращаюсь к Label1 мне пишет что такой переменной нет

Помогите исправить

Comment: Если StackLayout расположен в DataTemplate, то никак. Используйте mvvm паттерн.

Comment: StackLayout у меня находится только в ContentPage

Comment: у меня есть файл MainPage.xaml (в нём весь xaml код), а в нём MainPage.xaml.cs, метод находится в MainPage.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже решил проблему, оказывается надо было просто сохранить XAML код